# How to remove strings from all elements in array?

Tags: ruby

How can i remove a repeating string keyword from all elements in an array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean you have an array of strings and they all contain some substring that you want to remove. Non-destructively:

```
array.map {|s| s.gsub(keyword, '')}
```

Use destructive variants as desired to do it in-place.

Comment: here's a destructive (in-place) example: `array.each {|word| word.delete!('aeiou')}`

Comment: here's another destructive (in-place) example: `array.map! {|word| word.gsub(keyword,'')}`

Comment: we are the destructoglenns

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to string in the array, or non-unique elements.  For the first, use the uniq method:

```
p ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"].uniq
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

For the latter, try something like:

```
p ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz"].map { |x| x.gsub('oo', '') }
["f", "bar", "f", "baz"]
```